# How to authenticate a gcloud service account from within a docker container

Tags: dockerfile, gcloud

I’m trying to create a docker container that will execute a BigQuery query. I started with the Google provided image that had gcloud already and I add my bash script that has my query. I'm passing my service account key as an environment file.

Dockerfile

```
FROM gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:latest
COPY main.sh main.sh
```

main.sh

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account X@Y.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=/etc/secrets/service_account_key.json
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false
```

The gcloud command successfully authenticates but can't save to /.config/gcloud saying it is read-only. I've tried modifying that folders permissions during build and struggling to get it right.

Is this the right approach or is there a better way? If this is the right approach, how can I get ensure gcloud can write to the necessary folder?

Answer (score 2):

See the example at the bottom of the [Usage](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sdk-docker#usage) section.

You ought to be able to combine this into a single `docker run` command:

```sh
KEY="service_account_key.json"
echo "
[auth]
credential_file_override = /certs/${KEY}
" > ${PWD}/config

docker run \
--detach \
-env=CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=/config \
--volume=${PWD}/config:/config \
--volume=/etc/secrets/${KEY}:/certs/${KEY} \
gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:latest \
  bq query \
  --use_legacy_sql=false
```

Where:

- `--env` set the container's value for `CLOUDSDK_CONFIG` which depends on the first `--volume` flag which maps the host's `config` that we created in `${PWD}` to the container's `/config`.
- The second `--volume` flag maps the host's `/etc/secrets/${KEY}` (per your question) to the container's `/certs/${KEY}`. Change as you wish.
- Suitably configured (), you can run `bq`

I've not tried this but that should work :-)